# Position based dynamics constraint scaling factor

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, constrained-dynamics

Reading through [Müller et al., Position Based Dynamics, 2007](http://matthias-mueller-fischer.ch/publications/posBasedDyn.pdf) I got lost when passing from equation (5)

$$\Delta p = \frac{C(p)}{|\nabla_pC(p)|^2}\nabla_pC(p)$$

to equation (6) (and applying the scaling factor of equation (7))

$$\Delta p_i = \frac{-C(p_1,...,p_n)}{\sum_j|\nabla_{p_j}C(p_1,...,p_n)|^2}\nabla_{p_i}C(p_1,...,p_n)$$

I fully understand the way equation (5) was derived and why, but then I cannot figure out how for a particle $p_i$ the denominator becomes a sum over the dot product of the gradients, moreover what are the values for the index $j$? Are they the neighboring particles to $p_i$?

**EDIT**

I've been thinking about this for a while and I think I get it, It would be nice if someone can tell me if it is the right way to think about it.

Say, $p = (p_1, p_2)$, therefore $\nabla_p = (\frac{\partial}{\partial p_1}, \frac{\partial}{\partial p_2})$

Now, $\nabla_p C(p) = (\frac{\partial C(p1,p2)}{\partial p_1}, \frac{\partial C(p1,p2)}{\partial p_2})$

And, $|\nabla_p C(p)|^2 = <\nabla_p C(p),\nabla_p C(p)> = |\frac{\partial C(p1,p2)}{\partial p_1}|^2 + |\frac{\partial C(p1,p2)}{\partial p_2}|^2 = \sum_{j=1}^2 |\frac{\partial C(p1,p2)}{\partial p_j}|$

Answer (score 1):

The subscript $j$ represents all particles, including $i$, from 1 to $n$. This should be obvious in the example below Equation (9),

> To give an example, let us consider the distance constraing function $C(\mathbf p_1,\,\mathbf p_2)=\vert\mathbf p_1-\mathbf p_2\vert-d$. The derivative with respect to the points are $\nabla_{\mathbf p_1}C(\mathbf p_1,\,\mathbf p_2)= \mathbf  n$ and $\nabla_{\mathbf p_2}C(\mathbf p_1,\,\mathbf p_2)=-\mathbf n$ with $\mathbf n=\frac{\mathbf p_1-\mathbf p_2}{|\mathbf p_1-\mathbf p_2|}$. The scaling factor $s$ is, thus, $s=\frac{|\mathbf p_1-\mathbf p_2|-d}{w_1+w_2}$ and the final corrections...

Given the 2 particle system, then it must be that the sum over $j$ is over all particles 1 to $n$. (Note also that the $w_i$ terms come from the weight described before Equation (8)).

Comment: And how is it that from equation (5) goes to equation (6) with the denominator becoming a sum over all particles?

Comment: Equation (5) describes the *general* picture for some vector $\mathbf p$ whereas (6) is for an *individual* particle.

Comment: Yes, that's what I read from the text, but I don't understand why the squared norm in (5) becomes a sum of the squared norms in (6).

Comment: @BRabbit27, it looks like $p$ is a vector of all particle positions while $p_i$ is the position of just one.

Comment: @user3823992 yes it is, but still why is there a sum in the denominator? Sorry if this is so basic but I don't see why. What should I do to see where does that sum comes from? Should I do the derivatives of the whole thing at each $p_i$?

Comment: @BRabbit27: The paragraph before Equation (3) states *We let $\mathbf p$ be the concatenation $[\mathbf p_1^T,\ldots,\mathbf p_n^T]^T.$* So really Equation (5) has an *implicit* sum whereas (6) explicitly shows it.

Comment: Yes, it says it is the concatenation. What I want is to have it with symbols so that I know I'm doing the correct math. Did you see my edit? Is it the correct way of expanding the expression in equation (5) ?

Comment: @BRabbit27: That does appear to be the correct interpretation.